# How to load backbone model from an attribute in response?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am having trouble in binding an odata response to my model. Initially I had a simple model and a simple response which is working fine. But then I changed my response to be in odata format. My backbone modle is:

```
    var UserCard = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        ...
    }
});
```

and its related collection:

```
    var UserCards = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserCard,
    url: '/odata/UserCards'
});
```

now this collection was being populated until I changed the response which now looks like below:

```
{
 "odata.metadata":"http://website.com:53176/odata/$metadata#UserCards",
 "value":[{...},{...}...]
 }
```

When I call the `collection.fetch` method it tries to put the above in my model which is not compatible with this response. The model however is compatible with whatever is contained inside the value attribute of the above json.

I would like to find out if there is a way I can load my model from the `value` attribute instead of the full response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `parse()` method for your model/collection.  eg:

```
parse: function(data) {
    return data.value;
}
```

`parse` is the method Backbone calls when it retrieves data from the server, see [Backbone docs here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse)

Comment: No worries.  Happy backboning.

Comment: so far it's breaking my backbone :S